# Removing ads from Foxit Reader

Tags: advertisements, foxit-reader

I want to remove the ads from the title bar in Foxit Reader. Back in version 1.x, this was possible with a modification of the registry. Is there something similar for newer versions? I am using v3.3.1 now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Foxit Software - Technical FAQ :

> You can remove the Advertisements bar
>   easily by right-clicking on a blank
>   area of the toolbar and then uncheck
>   `Advertisement` on the context menu.

I also think I remember an "Advertisement" entry on the View menu in version 3 (I now use version 4).

Answer (score 4):

In Foxit Reader 6, released in 2013, it isn't so easy to turn of the advertisements as before. You now have to edit the registry.

1. Make sure Foxit Reader isn't currently running on your computer, then run Regedit.
2. Navigate to the following key:

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader 6.0\Preferences\General
3. Then change bShowAdvertisement value from **1** to **0**.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/587150/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-advertisement-in-foxit-reader-6-0 this question has an answer that seems to indicate otherwise. Coincidentally also found in "Preferences\General"