# Is it possible to remove the advertisement in Foxit Reader 6.0?

Tags: pdf, foxit-reader

Foxit Reader 6.0 has an advertisement in the top right corner of the screen:

[image: The advertisement of Foxit Reader]

Is it possible to remove this advertisement?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[image]

The new updates in Foxit Reader almost change the User Interface compared to Foxit 5.X

However, I just found a way to remove ads: File -> Preferences -> General

Comment: Does that option stick or does it get unchecked every time? I remember in previous versions you could right-click to hide ads, but they came back with a vengeance every time. If they're trying to make money from ads since the reader's free, sounds strange they'd allow users to permanently disable them.

Comment: The ads are permanently disabled. The ads are linked to Foxit's own products rather than outsider. I guess they make revenue from its other product lines (e.g. pdf editor, pdf creator, solution for business).

Comment: Confirmed working on latest version as of the date of this comment.

Comment: still works on version 8.1.4.1208