# How to disable title bar advertisment in foxit pdf reader 7

Tags: pdf-reader, foxit-reader

I am using foxit pdf reader for a long time and i always disabled the title bar advertisement using [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/587150/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-advertisement-in-foxit-reader-6-0). But recently I updated the foxit pdf reader to 7.0.6 and after that the advertisement has return and i am unable to disable the advertisement.

"**Show advertisement**" in general tab is unchecked (File -> Preferences -> General) and stays the same

I have also tried to edit the [registry](https://superuser.com/questions/185274/removing-ads-from-foxit-reader)

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader 7.0\Preferences\General
```

But the bShowAdvertisement value was already  **0**.

Any idea how to solve this problem

Comment: Have you tried enabling that option, closing foxit completely and reopening it and then disabling it again?

Comment: If you have more than one tab open, the advertisements seem to refresh every restart (despite the unticked box/registry setting). Note that there's also `Others\bShowAD`, though that doesn't change anything either.

Comment: I believe this option has been fixed in later versions, such as the current version 7.2.2.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable it via Preferences>General>Application Startup. There is an option to disable advertisement.

Comment: This was identified in bold in the question as not working.

Comment: Strange - it just worked for me. I'm on Foxit Reader 7.2.0.722.

Comment: Worked for me.
I disabled it because of the distraction factor, but is there a way to donate to the dev. team to make up for the loss of income and support them?